# Ошибка в цикле массива

Tags: javascript

По идее скрипт ниже должен вывести: **1, 8, 32,**

то есть должен суммироваться только второй элемент массива цифра **5**

Но скрипт выводит следующее: **8, 8, 11,** где я накосячил?

```js
let massive = [

1,

5,

32,

];


for(let i = 0; i < massive.length; i++){    
massive[i] = massive[1] + 3;
}

alert(massive);
```

Comment: Возьмите карандаш и листок бумаги, и запишите содержимое массива на каждом шаге Вашего цикла. На это понадобится не так много бумаги и времени.

Comment: Это хороший пример для тренеровки понимания. Но в реальных  задачах лучше не менять структуру по которой итерируетесь, а создавать другую, чтобы избежать подобных ошибок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let massive = [1, 5, 32];

for(let i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {    
  if (i == 1)
    massive[i] = massive[i] + 3;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(massive));
```

Не совсем понятно, зачем Вам здесь цикл.

```js
let massive = [1, 5, 32];

massive[1] = massive[1] + 3;

console.log(JSON.stringify(massive));
```

Comment: Громадное спасибо вам!